# Reducing the number of monitored files via FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net

My Windows Service application is writing logs to files in a folder every second. I want to monitor the log activities, if there are no logging for some time, it will signal error.

Below is an example of the log file names. Only the latest log file is being written into at a time, other files are not written into. The Monitor app cares about only the last log file.

```
MyApplication.MachineName.2018-06-05.log

MyApplication.MachineName.2018-06-04.001.log
```

Below is the code that monitors the log activities.

```
   private  void WatchFileChanges()
    {
        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = @"C:\Logs";
        /* Watch for changes in LastWrite times */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.log";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);


        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;       

    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private  void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {           
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);         
    }
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to reduce the number of log files being monitored under the folder? For example, monitor only log files for today, or last two days, rather than all files in the folder. Because the internal buffer is limited, excess log files might cause the monitoring not working.

Comment: Could you write the log files to a different folder each day (and just monitor a day or two of folders at a time)?

Comment: NO, that is not the current logic, and it is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a little bit creative here, and the simplest approach is just the [`FileSystemWatcher.Filter Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Gets or sets the filter string used to determine what files are
>   monitored in a directory.

**Remarks**

> To watch changes in all files, set the Filter property to an empty
>   string (`""`). To watch a specific file, set the Filter property to the
>   file name. For example, to watch for changes in the file `MyDoc.txt`,
>   set the Filter property to `"MyDoc.txt"`. You can also watch for changes
>   in a certain type of file. For example, to watch for changes in any
>   text files, set the Filter property to `"*.txt"`. Use of multiple
>   filters such as `"*.txt|*.doc"` is not supported.

**Some further examples**

> - `*.*` : All files (default). An empty string ("") also watches all files.
> - `*.txt` : All files with a "txt" extension.
> - `*recipe.doc` : All files ending in "recipe" with a "doc" extension.
> - `win*.xml` : All files beginning with "win" with an "xml" extension.
> - `Sales*200?.xls` :
>
>   - Matches the following:
>
>     - Sales July 2001.xls
>     - Sales Aug 2002.xls
>     - Sales March 2004.xls
>   - but does not match:
>
>     - Sales Nov 1999.xls
> - `MyReport.Doc` : Watches only MyReport.doc

Now with this information, you can easily determine if you can create a filter for the current days logs, and if you can, then you can change the filter dynamically each day to target those logs. As noted in the documentation

> The Filter property can be changed after the `FileSystemWatcher` object
>   has started receiving events.

Or as mentioned in the comments,

- Either put the days logs in a different folder
- If you are using a logging framework name your logs different for the current day so they "are" targetable
- Or increase the `FileSystemWatcher` buffer and monitor everything

This is your mission, if you choose to accept it.